# C# MySQL Query error handler

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio

I'm new in the Visual Studio world and I need a little help.

I'm writing a program C# based and it executes a query when a button is pressed:

```
 private void button_Login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MySqlDataAdapter start_session;

        start_session = new MySqlDataAdapter("HERE MY UPDATE QUERY", connection);

    }
```

(The connection string is on the top of the code).

Is there a way to check if the query returned errors or not ?

Thank you and sorry for (I presume) this really trivial question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to check if you get an error or not is "Exception".
Example (for SqlServer, MySQL is the same) :

```
private void buttonLoginClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        using (var sqLiteConnection = new SQLiteConnection(connString))
        {
            sqLiteConnection.Open();
            using (var sqLiteCommand = new SQLiteCommand(sql, sqLiteConnection))
            {
                sqLiteCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
        MessageBox.Show("Success");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error : " + ex.Message);
    }
}
```